# The Ngrok client connection fails

Tags: networking, ngrok

Server start command:

```
./ngrokd -domain="domain"
```

Client config:

```
server_addr: "domain:4443"
trust_host_root_certs: false
```

Server Log:

```
[16:41:59 CST 2023/06/14] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [registry] [tun] No affinity cache specified
[16:41:59 CST 2023/06/14] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Listening for public http connections on [::]:80
[16:41:59 CST 2023/06/14] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Listening for public https connections on [::]:443
[16:41:59 CST 2023/06/14] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Listening for control and proxy connections on [::]:4443
[16:41:59 CST 2023/06/14] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [metrics] Reporting every 30 seconds
[16:42:02 CST 2023/06/14] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [tun:6bc968eb] New connection from 60.28.35.84:32670
[16:42:02 CST 2023/06/14] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [tun:6bc968eb] Waiting to read message
[16:42:02 CST 2023/06/14] [WARN] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Warn:87) [tun:6bc968eb] Failed to read message: write tcp Server LAN IP:4443->Client WAN IP:32670: write: connection reset by peer
[16:42:02 CST 2023/06/14] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [tun:6bc968eb] Closing
```

Client Log:

```
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Reading configuration file ngrok.yml
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [client] Trusting root CAs: [assets/client/tls/ngrokroot.crt]
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [view] [web] Serving web interface on 127.0.0.1:4040
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [view] [term] Resize event, redrawing
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [view] [term] Resize event, redrawing
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Checking for update
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [view] [term] Waiting for update
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [view] [term] Waiting for update
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [view] [term] Waiting for update
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [ctl:e8667f5] New connection to: 60.205.142.33:4443
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [ctl:e8667f5] Writing message: {"Type":"Auth","Payload":{"Version":"2","MmVersion":"1.7","User":"","Password":"","OS":"windows","Arch":"amd64","ClientId":""}}
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [DEBG] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Debug:79) [ctl:e8667f5] Closing
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [EROR] (ngrok/log.Error:120) control recovering from failure read tcp Client LAN IP:53973->Server WAN IP:4443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[2023/06/14 16:42:02 CST] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Waiting 1 seconds before reconnecting
```

I tried to search for answers on Google, but couldn't find a similar question.